# How to deploy Camunda Platform 8 to production on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, camunda, helm3

I have tried to deploy Camunda Platform 8 using Helm Chart (https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/camunda-platform/camunda-platform) but am unable to use ingress or load balancer IP for identity service as it redirects to localohost:18080 for keycloak and there is no option for changing localhost:18080 to ingress ip in helm chart. So please suggest how to deploy camunda platform 8 on production on Kubernetes, mainly GKE.

Answer (score 2):

Like any helm chart you can overwrite the configuration values via separate (custom) values.yaml file. The exact entry for your yaml file will be
`global:`
 `identity.auth.publicIssuerUrl: *yourcustomtokenissuerendpoint*`

More details on helm global variables and how to use/override can be found here https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/#global-chart-values

Answer (score 0):

In case that helps: You can configure URLs like this:

```
global:
  image:
    tag: 8.0.0

  identity:
    auth:
      publicIssuerUrl: "https://camundakeycloak.my.cluster/auth/realms/camunda-platform"
      operate:
        existingSecret: camunda8-operate-identity-secret
        redirectUrl: "https://operate.my.cluster"
      optimize:
        existingSecret: camunda8-optimize-identity-secret
        redirectUrl: "https://optimize.my.cluster"
      tasklist:
        existingSecret: camunda8-tasklist-identity-secret
        redirectUrl: "https://tasklist.my.cluster"

identity:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    host: identity.my.cluster
    tls:
      enabled: true
      secretName: "my-tls-secret"

operate:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    host: operate.my.cluster
    tls:
      enabled: true
      secretName: "my-tls-secret"

optimize:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    host: optimize.my.cluster
    tls:
      enabled: true
      secretName: "my-tls-secret"

tasklist:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    host: tasklist.my.cluster
    tls:
      enabled: true
      secretName: "my-tls-secret"
```

But this will work up to the point where Keycloak writes the redirect url for the camunda-identity client, which is generated with http instead of https.